# Proof regarding the intersection of sigma-algebras.

Tags: measure-theory

I am very new to measure theory, and I am currently trying to prove elementary results. I have tried to prove that given $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A}_i$ for $i\in I$, where $I$ is an index set, that

$$\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$$

is itself a $\sigma$-algebra.

$\textbf{My proof is as follows:}$

Since $\mathcal{A}_i$ are $\sigma$-algebras, we trivially have that $Ø\in\mathcal{A}_i\ \forall i\in I\Rightarrow \bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$.

Suppose that $A\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$, then this implies that $A\in\mathcal{A}_i\ \forall i\in I$ by definition of the intersection. Since $\mathcal{A}_i$ are $\sigma$-algebras we have that $A^{c}\in\mathcal{A}_i\ \forall i\in I\Rightarrow A^{c}\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$.

Lastly, if we consider $A_k\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$ for $k\in K$, $K\subseteq I$, then $\forall k\in K$, $A_k\in\mathcal{A}_i\ \forall i\in I$, which implies $\bigcup_{k\in K}A_k\in\mathcal{A}_i\ \forall i\in I$ since $\mathcal{A}_i$ are $\sigma$-algebras. This shows that $\bigcup_{k\in K}A_k\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$.

Is this correct or am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not missing anything.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your comment!